# MS Graph - Get license assignment paths like GroupsAssigningLicense property in PowerShell

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm Looking for a way to get--using Microsoft Graph--license assignment paths (shown in the Licenses blade of the Microsoft Azure Portal) like the `GroupsAssigningLicense` property does on license objects in PowerShell.

I Need to be able to determine if user's license is coming from a group licensing assignment `("inherited")` or direct. Then must remove the direct licenses which have a corresponding inherited license. There's a good write-up on [how to do this from PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-licensing-ps-examples#remove-direct-licenses-for-users-with-group-licenses), but I can't find anything close to the critical piece (the `GroupsAssigningLicense` property) in MS Graph. We are modifying our self-service licensing app. Suspect equivalent functionality may not be available in MS Graph, yet.

Am I missing something? Is this being worked on?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is currently not available (as you've discovered). I'll go back to the team to find out what our plans are. In the meantime you can request this on [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis)

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks, @dan. This can now be found on UserVoice at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/19415752-get-license-assignment-paths-like-groupsassigningl

Comment: I have the same need. The linked UserVoice no longer exists. Has there been any change on this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Get-MgUser -Userid "user.name@domain.com"  -Select id, displayName, assignedLicenses, LicenseAssignmentStates,LicenseDetails, UserPrincipalName
```

What you should get as a result is this below, where you have the "AssignedByGroup" aka - the specific SkuId is assigned to user by Group with ID XXX. This shows you how it got there so you can filter those licenses based on this if it´s $null it´s direct, if it has group ID, it´s Group Based Licensing.

```
AssignedByGroup      : be549597-c5b9-4453-acdb-74f0f8275ff5
DisabledPlans        : {}
Error                : None
LastUpdatedDateTime  : 5/19/2023 11:18:51 AM
SkuId                : c5928f49-12ba-48f7-ada3-0d743a3601d5
State                : Active
AdditionalProperties : {}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

- $Get-MgSubscribedSku | Select -Property SkuPartNumber,ConsumedUnits,SkuId -ExpandProperty PrepaidUnits | Format-List
- $Get-MgUser -Filter "assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId eq a403ebcc-fae0-4ca2-8c8c-7a907fd6c235 )" | Select-Object UsageLocation